# How to print in html an array_keys in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print in html/php this array but doesn't work:

```
   $arr_active_languages = array(
        "en" => "English",
        "es" => "Español",
        "pt" => "Português",
        "fr" => "Français",
        "it" => "Italiano",
        "de" => "Deutsche"
    );
```

Html

```
<?php foreach($arr_active_languages as $lang): ?>
   <option value='<?php echo $lang[0]; ?>'><?php echo $lang[1]; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Look at example #2 at https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an associative array **arr_active_languages** not a 0-indexed array.
You can try the below code to make it work. Where **short_code** is the Key and **language** is the value of **arr_active_languages**

```php
$arr_active_languages = array(
    "en" => "English",
    "es" => "Español",
    "pt" => "Português",
    "fr" => "Français",
    "it" => "Italiano",
    "de" => "Deutsche"
);

<?php foreach($arr_active_languages as $short_code => $language): ?>
   <option value='<?php echo $short_code; ?>'><?php echo $language; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

PHP Official Documentation For **foreach()** Link Below:
[PHP Foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr_active_languages = array(
    "en" => "English",
    "es" => "Español",
    "pt" => "Português",
    "fr" => "Français",
    "it" => "Italiano",
    "de" => "Deutsche"
);

<?php foreach($arr_active_languages as $code=>$lang): ?>
   <option value='<?php echo $code; ?>'><?php echo $lang; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```